# How to use contextual parameters with AllowCode enabled

Tags: jsrender

How can you use contextual parameters when allow code is enabled?

This works:

```
{{for order itemVar='~i'}}
    {{: ~root.comments[~i].id }}
{{/for}}
```

But this doesn't work:

```
{{for order itemVar='~i'}}
    {{*: ~root.comments[~i].id }}
{{/for}}
```

Comment: Did my answer work for you? If so, perhaps you could 'accept' the answer... Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

In the context of an allowCode 'get' tag `{{*: ...}}` you can access not only global variables etc. but also the contextual data object, `data`, and the contextual view object, `view`.

To get contextual parameters you can use `view.ctx.paramName` or `view.ctxPrm("paramName")` (see https://www.jsviews.com/#tagsapi@ctxparams).

So for your example:

```
{{*: view.ctx.root.comments[view.ctx.i].id }}
```

or

```
{{*: view.ctxPrm("root").comments[view.ctxPrm("i")].id }}
```